# Vue variables are not set after I get them from api

Tags: vue.js, vue-chartjs

I have a chart.
this is my data:

```
        data() {
        return {
            title: 'registered users',
            type: 'line',
            users: null,
            labels: null,
            max: '',
        };
    },
```

I a got my vars:

```
methods: {
        loadUsers() {
            axios.get('/karma/post-users-chart')
                .then(({data}) => {
                    this.users = data.users;
                    this.labels = data.labels;
                    this.max = data.max;
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        },

    },
```

and when I assign them or console.log(this.users), they are empty
where is my problem??

```
mounted() {
        this.loadUsers();
console.log(this.users); // it returns null
```

but in vue pluging in chrome variables are set

Comment: `loadUsers()` is executed asynchronously, so it returns immediately after you call in `mounted()` but the response might not have come from server.

Comment: Your console log isn't waiting for the loadUsers function to finish. Put the console.log(this.users) in the loadUsers() method and see what happens.

Comment: If I put console.log in loadUsers() it's working just in .then()  but I have that problem again that                     this.users returns null

Answer (score 1):

`mounted` is synchronous. `loadUsers` is doing something asynchronous, but is executing it through a synchronous function. Either turn both of them into an `async` function and use `await` or have `loadUsers` return a promise that's resolved inside the `then`, which the `mounted` function then also assigns the value to `this.users`.

### async method

```
methods: {
        async loadUsers() {
            let { data } = await axios.get('/karma/post-users-chart')
            this.users = data.users
            this.labels = data.labels
            this.max = data.max
        },
    },


async mounted() {
    await this.loadUsers();
    console.log(this.users); // it returns null
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks its working now but my another function that is not async and it should be in mounted() , throws error now

this.createChart({

Comment: maybe you don't have that function setup yet?